# Remote repository and Gemfile.lock - Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a problem working with a remote repository. I do `git clone <URL>` just fine.
The problem is when I run `bundle`. I get loads of errors. Those errors are fixed by using `bundle update`, as it installs all the gems and then I can run everything fine. The problem is that my Gemfile.lock file gets changed and it comes as a file to be committed in the git repository (which it should not, because it will mess up the remote repository's Gemfile.lock file). Now I cannot push Gemfile .lock to the remote repository as it will break everything. But the strange part was that this Gemfile.lock is not included in the .gitignore file... So any ideas how I can overcome this or could somebody explain to me what exactly is going on ?

Comment: Why don't you put this file in .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `bundle`, bundler will use the gems that are listed in the `Gemfile.lock`.  `bundle update` updates the `Gemfile.lock` to get the latest of all gems listed in the `Gemfile` while still satisfying all dependencies.

You can run `bundle update` on a particular gem as well, which will limit the `Gemfile.lock` changes to dependencies of said gem.

You need to be a little more clear about which errors you are receiving?  Are they dependency related? or are you not able to build a gem with native extensions? or something else?  are you using gemsets - if not, that might be useful to prevent gem collisions.

Is there really a problem with `Gemfile.lock` being committed?  Are you a contributor to the repository?

Additionally, `bundler` gets updated every now and then.  You may want to update your version of `bundler` before running `bundle`.

```
gem update bundler
```